# Prometheus alertmanager emails issue

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-alertmanager

I have configured Prometheus with its alert manager and installed node exporter to monitor the metrics of OS.

After setting up the alert rule as below

```
groups:
 - name: test
   rules:
   - alert: InstanceDown
     expr: up == 0
     for: 1m
```

alert manager fires the alert when I manually shut down the node_exporter

[image: screenshot showing fired alert]

But I am not receiving any emails, please see the below the configurations of alertmanager.yml

```
route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receiver: 'mail'
receivers:
  - name: 'mail'
    email_configs:
      - to: anas.raza@ndctech.net
        from: infinity@ndctech.net
        smarthost: smtp.office365.com:587
        auth_username: infinity@ndctech.net
        auth_identity: infinity@ndctech.net
        auth_password: <password>
        send_resolved: true

inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']
```

Nothing is appearing on logs

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2022-04-11 23:13:25 PKT. --
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam systemd[1]: Started Alertmanager for prometheus.
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:49.822Z caller=main.go:231 level=info msg="Starting Alertmanager" version="(version=0.24.0, branch=HEAD, revision=f484b17fa3c583ed1b2c8bbcec20ba1db2aa5f11)"
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:49.822Z caller=main.go:232 level=info build_context="(go=go1.17.8, user=root@265f14f5c6fc, date=20220325-09:31:33)"
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:49.830Z caller=cluster.go:185 level=info component=cluster msg="setting advertise address explicitly" addr=10.0.18.112 port=9094
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:49.834Z caller=cluster.go:680 level=info component=cluster msg="Waiting for gossip to settle..." interval=2s
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:49.945Z caller=coordinator.go:113 level=info component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file" file=/root/Anas/alertmanager-0.24.0.linux-amd64/alertmanager.yml
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:49.947Z caller=coordinator.go:126 level=info component=configuration msg="Completed loading of configuration file" file=/root/Anas/alertmanager-0.24.0.linux-amd64/alertmanager.yml
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:49.956Z caller=main.go:535 level=info msg=Listening address=:9093
May 17 03:56:49 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:49.956Z caller=tls_config.go:195 level=info msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false
May 17 03:56:51 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:51.834Z caller=cluster.go:705 level=info component=cluster msg="gossip not settled" polls=0 before=0 now=1 elapsed=2.000102438s
May 17 03:56:59 rhpam alertmanager[50296]: ts=2022-05-16T22:56:59.837Z caller=cluster.go:697 level=info component=cluster msg="gossip settled; proceeding" elapsed=10.002818464s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your config (email_configs)  is not correct.
then change the config and restart alertmanager and check status.
if status is not active  , check logs and error with `sudo journalctl -eu alertmanager.service`